# OneLogin php-saml AuthNRequestID wrong

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I'm trying to configure php-saml Toolkit to connect my PHP website to Keycloak IdP.
I'm using the following configuration file

```
$settings = array (

'strict' => true,


'debug' => false,


'baseurl' => 'https://website.com',

// Service Provider Data that we are deploying
'sp' => array (
    // Identifier of the SP entity  (must be a URI)
    'entityId' => 'https://website.com/saml/sso/metadata.php',
    
    'assertionConsumerService' => array (
       
        'url' => 'https://website.com/saml/sso/index.php?acs',
        
        'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
    ),
   
    'singleLogoutService' => array (
        /
        'url' => 'https://mywebsite.com/saml/sso/index.php?slo',
       
        'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
    ),
   
    'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',

    
    'x509cert' => 'XXXXX',
    'privateKey' => 'XXXXXX',

    
),

// Identity Provider Data that we want connect with our SP
'idp' => array (
    
    'entityId' => 'https://idp.example.it/auth/realms/example',
    
    'singleSignOnService' => array (
        
        'url' => 'https://idp.example.it/auth/realms/example/protocol/saml',
        
        'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
    ),
    // SLO endpoint info of the IdP.
    'singleLogoutService' => array (
        
        'url' => 'https://idp.example.it/auth/realms/example/protocol/saml',
        
        'responseUrl' => 'https://idp.example.it/auth/realms/example/protocol/saml',
        
        'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
    ),
   
    'x509cert' => 'XXXXX',

),);
```

When I ask for login, I'm correctly redirect to the IdP and the SAMLResponse are posted to the SP, the problem is that the control on AuthNRequestID fails. Enabling the debug the message is the follow:

The InResponseTo of the Response: ONELOGIN_bcc26f9f5841a472cc3418c5b5720163ecb03b9e, does not match the ID of the AuthNRequest sent by the SP: ONELOGIN_966fd52438c025fc01623d297dd5192ed58b9eeb

Which could be the problem?

Comment: If this can help, I have used also OneLogin SAML Wordpress plugin in an other website and it works. I think that the plugin uses the same Toolkit

Comment: have you tried using HTTP-POST binding instead of redirect binding? Can you paste the entire SAMLResponse you are getting once the user is authenticated?